# How to send "empty" variable into JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I have some functional tests created via JMeter. It is pretty huge but i can't handle one simple check. 
I generate properties using BSF pre processor with help of JS. Parameter (lets call it "payment_fee") should be generated only if other parameter (lets call it "role") has a value = 1 .In this case we post pre generated integer into payment_fee and everything works well. But if role =2 then we should post nothing into payment_fee.
The problem is, i don't know how to say to JMeter: In case if role = 1 use variable with pre generated payment_fee but if role = 2, you shouldn't use this variable so just post an empty value for payment_fee  . Server waits for an integer so empty string or NULL had been rejected.

For more clarification:
I will try to explain more clear.
Here is a part of my code

```
        var role = Math.floor(Math.random()*3+1)
        var paymentType = ["creditcard","cash"]
        var randomPay = installerType[Math.floor(Math.random()*installerType.length)];
        var payment = "";
        var paymentFee;
        if (role == 1){
            payment+=randomPay,
            paymentFee = Math.floor((Math.random() * 999) + 1) / 10.00
        }
vars.put("role", role);
vars.put("payment", payment);
vars.put("paymentFee", paymentFee);
```

And if role == 1 i should post paymentFee value. Like this - http://prntscr.com/b50kk1 BUT! if role == 2 || role == 3 I should remove this value, so it should be like this http://prnt.sc/b50l82

Comment: how "role" is generated? post your BSF code if it's relevant to parameter generation

Comment: 3 roles are available, and for role 2 and 3 i should send an empty payment_fee parameter.
var role = Math.floor(Math.random()*3+1);

Comment: then what prevents you from setting payment_fee in the same code, i.e. `if(role==1) vars.put("payment_fee", "1"); else vars.put("payment_fee", "");`
And then in smapler just use `${payment_fee}` for variable

Comment: Man, thank you, but i mentioned above that:

Server waits for an integer so empty string or NULL had been rejected.

And you proposing me to place an empty string as value. And yes, if it is so simple as you wrote i wouldn't create such topic.

Comment: I think you are confused: if `${paymentFee}` is set to value `""`, the behavior will be identical to what you show in the second screenshot. There is no, and cannot be difference. The problem in your code is that you don't set it to anything by default. You need to add `else { paymentFee="" }` after `if`.

Comment: Damn, so stupid mistake. I was sure that  var paymentFee = ""; by default, and not create else for it. Thanks man.

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand what you're trying to do as your 2 statements clash:

- But if role =2 then we should post **nothing** into payment_fee
- Server waits for an integer so **empty string or NULL had been rejected**

You should know few bits about JMeter properties:

1. Properties are global for the whole [JVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine). Once you set property it will "live" until you exit JMeter.
2. Properties can be accesses by all threads of all [Thread Groups](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group).

So it might be the case when you define property earlier or by another thread and expect it to be not set later on.

Also BSF PreProcessor and JavaScript isn't the best combination from performance perspective, consider switching to [JSR223 PreProcessor and Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/beanshell-vs-jsr223-vs-java-jmeter-scripting-its-performance).

Comment: Thank you for your answer but this is not the thing that i am looking for. I think i was not so clear in my question, so i edited it. Please check it, i think now you will fully understand it.